# OAuth/authorization end point is not returning with expected http 302 status, also session id and token information is missing in the response

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jhipster, okta

I am upgrading my jhipster application to the latest jhipster version which is 7.6.0.
Jhipster 7.6.0 introduces latest version of spring boot (2.6.3) and spring framework (5.3.15)

For security configuration class, I am still using the annotations from spring web mvc and I am not using spring web reactive. At this point, I dont want to switch to web reactive.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@Import(SecurityProblemSupport.class)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter { }
```

After compiling, building and starting my application, If I hit the login url, then I get below error on the screen

```
Login with OAuth 2.0
[invalid_user_info_response] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the UserInfo Resource: 403 Forbidden: [no body]
```

Browser's DevTools console shows that OAuth/authorization end point is returning with 200 http status with no values for session id and token, whereas ideally the end point should return with http status 302 along with session id and token.

I suspect, its related to the changes introduced by the version upgrade, because If I switch back to the older branch of the source code (having older version of jhipster like 6.4.1 and spring) , then the login works just fine.

Can anyone suggest what could be the possible reason behind this issue?
I believe that the 'authorize' end point returning 200 response with missing session id and token is surely one of the reasons.
Please guide me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: The error is telling you that the UserInfo cannot be retrieved, have you configured the url correctly? You may find this useful [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-security.html)

Comment: @Pablo....Thanks for sharing the link. I will check the details. But, If the url is incorrect , then it should not work if I switch the source code to the old branch having old version of Jhipster and spring boot and spring security. However, that's not the case. Everything works fine if I switch to the old source code. I am trying to understand if the latest version of spring security needs any particular configuration without which the authorization may not work.

Comment: One thing that changed in Spring Boot 2.6 was adding the [`SameSite` cookie attribute](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.0/reference/html//web.html#web.servlet.embedded-container.customizing.samesite). This could be causing the behaviour you described. You can try setting the following property `server.servlet.session.cookie.same-site=none` and see if it makes your application run as expected. If this is the cause you can decide how to proceed based on the information provided in the linked documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the details. I have found the root cause. For the latest version of spring security, oidc: scope needs to be mentioned explicitly. something like this - scope: openid,profile,email. Adding this scope in application yml fixed the issue. –